# Creating a popup form in django

Tags: django, bootstrap-modal

My django application has 4 buttons where each button opens a popup form upon clicking that button. After filling that popup form, my button should have right mark on it so that user can get to know that it is completed. Below these four buttons, i have submit button which posts all these forms details to database.

I can make a popup with modal in bootstrap. but i want this button to be clicked or set right mark on button after completing that popup form.  I am confused on how to achieve this with django or bootstrap?

And also, do i have to create a separate view for every popup form in my django views.py file? and how does that button store form values so that it will post these values upon clicking submit button?

Edit: my button looks like below

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-
target="#myModal">Button Name</button>
```

Upon clicking that above button, a popup appears which have form contains 4 fields. I want to get these form values in my views.py file. But i do not have urlconf for that button. when i create a separate URL for the button, form no longer comes in popup or dialog box. How to get those form values in my views.py file or how to process those form variables? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

> i want this button to be clicked or set right mark on button after completing that popup form. I am confused on how to achieve this with django or bootstrap?

Either you have to reload your 'base' form page again after submitting the popup - with some variable that tells the template to display the button as 'done'. Or you use javascript. HTML pages/elements do not magically change on their own; either the page needs to be reloaded or javascript has it's evil fingers in it.

> And also, do i have to create a separate view for every popup form in my django views.py file?

While you can 'reroute' the requests that the buttons send back into the original view through the clever use of captured parameters in your url conf, I would suggest you just make a view for each button. Easier to test, easier on your sanity.

> and how does that button store form values so that it will post these values upon clicking submit button?

[Request sessions come to mind.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/)

---

Maybe [formtool's WizardView](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html) would be more appropiate for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. When i create separate view for button, my modal form appearing in separate window rather than as a popup

Comment: And when i say, do i have to create a separate view for every popup form in my django views.py file, does that mean that i have to create separate url for every popup form?